# The fundamental equation of a system

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, definition

I was reading Thermodynamics and an I（second edition） by Callen and thinking about the problem in P92.
A particular system is constrained to a constant mole number and volume so that no work can be done on or by the system. Furthermore, the heat capacity of the system is $C$, a constant.
How can we find the fundamental equation? ARE $U(T,V,N)$ AND $S(T,V,N)$ enough to determine the fundamental equation? Is the system similar to the system with fundamental equations $pV=NRT$ and $U=cNRT$; how can we derive $p$ and $μ$?

Comment: This is one of my favorite books in thermodynamics. The four postulates are a very nice way Callen describes the fundamental equation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to a long tradition in Thermodynamics, a fundamental equation is a thermodynamic function of the state from which all the thermodynamic properties can be derived without the need to introduce arbitrary constants of state-dependent functions. Examples of fundamental equations are the entropy $S$ as a function of internal energy $U$, volume $V$, and the number of moles $N$, $U(S,V,N)$, all the so-called thermodynamic potentials (Helmholtz free energy, Gibbs free energy, enthalpy) and all the Massieu functions obtained from the entropy fundamental equation.

The equations you cite ( $pV=NRT$ and $U=cNRT$ ), according to Callen's terminology, are not fundamental equations but can be recast in the form
of *equations of state*, i.e., expressions for the first derivatives of the fundamental equation $S(U,V,N)$ with respect to the volume and the energy.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{p}{T}&= \left. \frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{V}} \right|_{U,N}=\frac{NR}{V} \tag{1}\\
\frac{1}{T}&=\left. \frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{U}} \right|_{V,N}=\frac{cNR}{U}.\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

In Callen's book, there is a clear discussion of how, from equations $(1)$ and $(2)$, it is possible to obtain the explicit fundamental equation $S(U,V,N)$ within an arbitrary constant, by using Gibbs-Duhem relation.
$$
d\left( \frac{\mu}{T} \right) = \frac{U}{N} d\left( \frac{1}{T} \right)+
 \frac{V}{N} d\left( \frac{p}{T} \right).
$$

Now, I come to your main question

> are $U(T,V,N)$ and $S(T,V,N)$ enough to determine the fundamental equation?

Yes, if you know both, they are enough. The main point is that one can get the energy ($U(S,V,N)$) or the entropy ($S(U,V,N)$) fundamental equations from  $U(T,V,N)$ or $S(T,V,N)$ if it is possible to get either $T(U,V,N)$ or $T(S,V,N)$.
This is certainly possible, using data at constant $V$ and $N$ (for different volumes and number of moles), because the partial derivatives of $U$ or $S$ with respect to $T$ at constant $V$ and $N$ are positive. Therefore it is possible to use the inverse function theorem to get $T(U,V,N)$ or $T(S,V,N)$ and consequently the corresponding fundamental equation.

Comment: But how do you derive the fundamental equation of the system? I have the answer s=s0+lnu/u0 but is it a fundamental equation?

Comment: According to Callen U(T,V,N) isn't enough to find the fundamental equation , see p64 of the book .

Comment: @Raffaella, Maybe I misunderstood your question. If you ask if it is possible to recover $S(U,V,N)$ by knowledge of **both**  $(,,)$ AND  $(,,)$ my answer is yes, and it is not in contradiction with Callen's book. What Callen explains at p. 64 of his book is that from $S(T,V,N)$ *alone* it is not possible to get $S(U,V,N)$. But in your question, apparently, you were considering $(,,)$ AND  $(,,)$.

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fundamental equation $dU = dq + dw$ (just make sure what convention your book uses for signs) and you'd get $$dU = TdS-pdV$$ which shows that $U$ and $S$ are enough to get the fundamental equation.

For the given conditions the system is similar to fundamental equations of PV=NRT and U=cNRT since those are derivable from the mentioned $dU$ equation.

To derive P and $\mu$ you can see, $$\mu = \frac{dU}{dn}$$ so you have an idea of what $\mu$ will be. I don't understand why you're asking for $\mu$ since moles is constant so there no exchange of matter in system. And for P you can the PV=NRT equation

Comment: Sorry But this system doesn't necessarily satisfy your equation of statePV=NRT

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you're talking about the problem given on p92 of the book you mentioned where they are trying to get work done on a lift. According to me with the given conditions the PV=NRT would be applicable here it just so happens that for that question it is not required and doesn't have enough data to apply it

Comment: Your equation for $dU$ is not a fundamental equation, accordingly to Callen's terminology.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I'm not familiar with the terminology of the book and I had to google what fundamental equations are. So I found that this is known as a fundamental equation through chemlibretext. For my education I've always used Equation of State as the terminology. Apologies for any confusion